# Декодирование текста

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
def read(url, n):
import urllib.request
file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
contents = file.readlines(n)
for items in contents:
    print(items)
```

При работе с украинским текстом такой результат:

```
b'\xd0\x92\xd0\x90\xd0\x96\xd0\x9b\xd0\x98\xd0\x92\xd0\x86 \xd0\xa7\xd0\x98\xd0\xa1\xd0\x9b\xd0\x90:\t \n'
```

Как вивести кирилицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от кодировки сайта. В данном случае, похоже что, это utf-8 кодированное в hex.

Нужно декодировать из utf-8.

```
print(items.decode('utf-8'))


b'\xd0\x92\xd0\x90\xd0\x96\xd0\x9b\xd0\x98\xd0\x92\xd0\x86 \xd0\xa7\xd0\x98\xd0\xa1\xd0\x9b\xd0\x90:\t \n'.decode('utf-8') //ВАЖЛИВІ ЧИСЛА:\t \n
```